# PHP Abstract Class extends Exception

Tags: php, oop, exception, abstract

I was wondering if an abstract class like MyException could extends Exception class or not.
I would create a generic MyException Class that then I will use how parent of some not abstract specific exceptions classes. 
Here's an example

```
abstract class GenericException extends \Exception {
    public function __construct($message, $code) {
        parent::__construct($message, $code);
    }
    // some abstract methods
}
class SpecificException extends GenericException {
    // implementation abstract method of GerericException
    // some-code
}
```

ecc.

Another question: parent call must be the first call like in Java or not?

Comment: In PHP manual, there is an example for the same: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php

Comment: I had already read but the abstract class that extends Exception there isn't how the parent call roule.

Comment: Yes, you can do it. I'd rather skip the abstract class and just extend Exception directly, but nothing prevents you from doing that.